Getting BigInt error while trying to implement a sendtransaction function
I am working on a  browser extension and using the following library bitgo/utxo
It works fine if I am running it in a standalone nodejs file as .cjs.
However the same version is not working in my extension and I get this when trying to broadcast or send a transaction. I am not using BigInt
Relevant UTXOs for currency: 1
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Initializing transaction builder...
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Setting transaction version and group ID...
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Adding inputs to transaction...
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Adding input: {txid: 'd50479e0700a0acd117ef26c11ea3eb4efe4feb88f69b3c36a4fce8c193fd992', outputIndex: 1, satoshis: 98999980000}
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Running total: 989.9998 VRSCTEST
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Adding recipient output: {toAddress: 'RJUrMCBDBCR4RH3vKqQ6QtJNDsppkJi87i', amount: 6000000000, inVRSC: 60}
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Adding change output: {toAddress: 'RVjqTMnCsqMQrZ6fcNKq9dMy3mhQrx46AM', amount: 92999960000, inVRSC: 929.9996}
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Change output added: 929.9996 VRSCTEST
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Starting to sign inputs...
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Signing input 0 {address: 'RVjqTMnCsqMQrZ6fcNKq9dMy3mhQrx46AM', blocktime: 1733711681, height: 333709, isspendable: 1, outputIndex: 1, …}
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Manually deriving publicKey...
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 KeyPair publicKey: 035059bf088580899127a535aee089371feaa01ea9f8c93d2f126302e4708725d8
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 PrevOutScript (hex): 76a914e06c87f625f5ee4cdccf980a963e4f43c24b000688ac
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Input at index 0 {}
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Witness value: 98999980000
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Error signing input 0 TfTypeError$1 {__error: Error
    at new TfTypeError$1 (chrome-extension://nldfncijlaejkdligmcipjjdoiofebbl/assets/popup-C8…, __value: 98999980000n, __valueTypeName: undefined, __type: ƒ}
sendCurrency @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
await in sendCurrency
X @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
await in X
(anonymous) @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
n.<computed>.n.<computed> @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:20
callWithErrorHandling @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:16
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:16
n @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:20Understand this errorAI
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Error in sendCurrency: TfTypeError$1 {__error: Error
    at new TfTypeError$1 (chrome-extension://nldfncijlaejkdligmcipjjdoiofebbl/assets/popup-C8…, __value: 98999980000n, __valueTypeName: undefined, __type: ƒ}
sendCurrency @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
await in sendCurrency
X @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
await in X
(anonymous) @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
n.<computed>.n.<computed> @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:20
callWithErrorHandling @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:16
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:16
n @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:20Understand this errorAI
popup-C82cGM_V.js:150 Send transaction failed: TfTypeError$1 {__error: Error
    at new TfTypeError$1 (chrome-extension://nldfncijlaejkdligmcipjjdoiofebbl/assets/popup-C8…, __value: 98999980000n, __valueTypeName: undefined, __type: ƒ}
X @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
await in X
(anonymous) @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:150
n.<computed>.n.<computed> @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:20
callWithErrorHandling @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:16
callWithAsyncErrorHandling @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:16
n @ popup-C82cGM_V.js:20Understand this errorAI

This is the code for transaction.js
import { makeRPCCall } from './verus-rpc';
import * as bitcoin from '@bitgo/utxo-lib';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';


global.Buffer = Buffer;

// Network configuration for Verus
const NETWORK = bitcoin.networks.verustest;
const { ECPair, TransactionBuilder } = bitcoin;

// Constants
const SATS_PER_COIN = 100000000;
const DUST_THRESHOLD = 546;
const DEFAULT_FEE = 20000; // 0.0002 VRSC fee

/**
 * Send currency from one address to another
 * @param {string} fromAddress - Sender's address
 * @param {string} toAddress - Recipient's address
 * @param {number} amount - Amount to send (in VRSCTEST)
 * @param {string} privateKeyWIF - Sender's private key in WIF format
 * @param {string} currency - Currency to send (default: 'VRSCTEST')
 * @returns {Promise<{txid: string}>}
 */
export async function sendCurrency(fromAddress, toAddress, amount, privateKeyWIF, currency = 'VRSCTEST') {
    try {
        console.log('Starting sendCurrency with params:', { fromAddress, toAddress, amount, currency });
        
        // Test RPC connection first
        try {
            const testResponse = await makeRPCCall('getinfo', []);
            console.log('RPC connection test successful:', testResponse);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('RPC connection test failed:', error);
            throw new Error('Failed to connect to Verus RPC server: ' + error.message);
        }
        
        // Validate private key format
        if (!privateKeyWIF) {
            throw new Error('Private key is required');
        }

        // Validate that the private key is in WIF format
        let keyPair;
        try {
            keyPair = ECPair.fromWIF(privateKeyWIF, NETWORK);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Invalid private key:', error);
            throw new Error('Invalid private key format. Must be in WIF format.');
        }

        // Step 1: Fetch UTXOs
        console.log('Fetching UTXOs for address:', fromAddress);
        const utxos = await makeRPCCall('getaddressutxos', [{
            addresses: [fromAddress],
            currencynames: true
        }]);
        
        if (!utxos || utxos.length === 0) {
            throw new Error('No UTXOs available');
        }

        console.log('Raw UTXOs:', JSON.stringify(utxos, null, 2));
        console.log('Found UTXOs:', utxos.length);

        // Filter UTXOs with VRSCTEST balance and normalize values
        const relevantUtxos = utxos.filter(utxo => utxo.satoshis > 0).map(utxo => {
            // The value we get is in VRSC, need to convert to satoshis
            const valueInVRSC = utxo.satoshis / SATS_PER_COIN;
            console.log(`Converting UTXO value: ${utxo.satoshis} (${valueInVRSC} VRSC) to satoshis`);
            return {
                ...utxo,
                originalValue: utxo.satoshis,
                satoshis: utxo.satoshis
            };
        });
        console.log('Relevant UTXOs:', JSON.stringify(relevantUtxos, null, 2));
        console.log('Relevant UTXOs for currency:', relevantUtxos.length);

        if (relevantUtxos.length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`No UTXOs available for ${currency}`);
        }

        // Build transaction
        console.log('Initializing transaction builder...');
        const txBuilder = new TransactionBuilder(NETWORK);
        
        // Set version for Overwinter support
        console.log('Setting transaction version and group ID...');
        txBuilder.setVersion(4);
        txBuilder.setVersionGroupId(0x892f2085);

        // Add all inputs
        console.log('Adding inputs to transaction...');
        let runningTotal = 0;
        for (const utxo of relevantUtxos) {
            console.log('Adding input:', {
                txid: utxo.txid,
                outputIndex: utxo.outputIndex,
                satoshis: utxo.satoshis
            });
            txBuilder.addInput(utxo.txid, utxo.outputIndex);
            runningTotal += utxo.satoshis;
            console.log('Running total:', runningTotal / SATS_PER_COIN, currency);
        }

        // Calculate output amounts
        const satoshisToSend = Math.floor(amount * SATS_PER_COIN);
        const fee = DEFAULT_FEE;
        
        if (runningTotal < satoshisToSend + fee) {
            throw new Error(`Insufficient funds. Required: ${(satoshisToSend + fee) / SATS_PER_COIN} ${currency}, Available: ${runningTotal / SATS_PER_COIN} ${currency}`);
        }

        // Add recipient output
        console.log('Adding recipient output:', { 
            toAddress, 
            amount: satoshisToSend,
            inVRSC: satoshisToSend / SATS_PER_COIN 
        });
        txBuilder.addOutput(toAddress, satoshisToSend);

        // Calculate and add change output
        const changeAmount = runningTotal - satoshisToSend - fee;
        if (changeAmount > DUST_THRESHOLD) {
            console.log('Adding change output:', { 
                toAddress: fromAddress, 
                amount: changeAmount,
                inVRSC: changeAmount / SATS_PER_COIN 
            });
            txBuilder.addOutput(fromAddress, changeAmount);
            console.log('Change output added:', changeAmount / SATS_PER_COIN, currency);
        }

        // Sign all inputs
        console.log('Starting to sign inputs...');
        // ... (other imports and constants remain unchanged)

        for (let i = 0; i < relevantUtxos.length; i++) {
            const utxo = relevantUtxos[i];
            console.log('Signing input', i, utxo);
        
            try {
                const hashType = bitcoin.Transaction.SIGHASH_ALL;
        
                // Validate KeyPair
                let keyPair = ECPair.fromWIF(privateKeyWIF, NETWORK);
                if (!keyPair.publicKey) {
                    console.log('Manually deriving publicKey...');
                    keyPair.publicKey = keyPair.getPublicKeyBuffer();
                }
                console.log('KeyPair publicKey:', keyPair.publicKey ? keyPair.publicKey.toString('hex') : 'undefined');
        
                // Generate previous output script
                const prevOutScript = bitcoin.address.toOutputScript(fromAddress, NETWORK);
                console.log('PrevOutScript (hex):', prevOutScript.toString('hex'));
        
                // Debug TransactionBuilder inputs
                const input = txBuilder.inputs[i];
                console.log('Input at index', i, input);
        
                // Convert witness value to Number and ensure it's a valid number
                const witnessValue = typeof utxo.satoshis === 'object' && utxo.satoshis.toString ? 
                    parseInt(utxo.satoshis.toString()) : 
                    Number(utxo.satoshis);
                    
                if (isNaN(witnessValue)) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid witness value: ' + utxo.satoshis);
                }
                console.log('Witness value:', witnessValue);

                // Signing
                txBuilder.sign(
                    i,
                    keyPair,
                    null,
                    bitcoin.Transaction.SIGHASH_ALL,
                    BigInt(relevantUtxos[i].satoshis) // Convert to BigInt explicitly
                );
        
                console.log('Successfully signed input', i);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error signing input', i, error);
                throw error;
            }
        }
        
        

        // Build and serialize transaction
        console.log('Building transaction...');
        const tx = txBuilder.build();
        const serializedTx = tx.toHex();
        console.log('Transaction built and serialized');

        // Broadcast transaction
        console.log('Broadcasting transaction...');
        const txid = await makeRPCCall('sendrawtransaction', [serializedTx]);
        
        console.log('Transaction broadcast successful. TXID:', txid);
        return { txid };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in sendCurrency:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Estimate transaction fee
 * @param {string} fromAddress - Sender's address
 * @param {number} amount - Amount to send
 * @param {string} currency - Currency to send
 * @returns {Promise<number>} Estimated fee in VRSCTEST
 */
export async function estimateFee(fromAddress, amount, currency = 'VRSCTEST') {
    try {
        const utxos = await makeRPCCall('getaddressutxos', [{
            addresses: [fromAddress],
            currencynames: true
        }]);
        
        const baseFee = 0.001;
        const inputCount = utxos.length;
        const outputCount = 2;
        
        const estimatedSize = (inputCount * 180) + (outputCount * 34) + 10;
        const feeRate = 1;
        const calculatedFee = (estimatedSize * feeRate) / 100000000;
        
        return Math.max(baseFee, calculatedFee);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error estimating fee:', error);
        throw error;
    }
}

/**
 * Validate a Verus address
 * @param {string} address - Address to validate
 * @returns {boolean} Whether the address is valid
 */
export function validateAddress(address) {
    try {
        // Verus addresses start with 'R'
        if (!address.startsWith('R')) {
            return false;
        }

        // Try to decode the address
        bitcoin.address.fromBase58Check(address);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Address validation error:', error);
        return false;
    }
}



When it runs to the error, what is the last line in the log?

The error is the last line

So you have a bunch of console.log and console.error statements in your code. What do they print to the console?

Have updated the code and the errors

this is due to a type mismatch between Node.js and browser environments when handling BigInt values with @bitgo/utxo-lib. This commonly happens because browser extensions handle BigInt differently than Node.js.
Try modifying your transaction signing code like this:
for (let i = 0; i < relevantUtxos.length; i++) {
    txBuilder.sign(
        i,
        keyPair,
        null,
        bitcoin.Transaction.SIGHASH_ALL,
        BigInt(relevantUtxos[i].satoshis) // Convert to BigInt explicitly
    );
}

Also, ensure you're using the correct bundler configuration for your browser extension. Add these to your bundler config:
{
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
            "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify"),
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/")
        }
    }
}


And add these polyfills to your entry point:
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
global.Buffer = Buffer;

This should resolve the BigInt type error while maintaining compatibility with both Node.js and browser environments.

Same error check the updated code and errors
